# Exception in thread "Thread" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access - With Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, opencv, ocr

I have two threads that run when i open the form, then close this form to go a new forms, then i return to the form with threads and i receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:383)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.TessBaseAPIInit2(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:281)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:215)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:166)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:151)
    at utilitario.Util.procesaImagen(Util.java:22)
    at pantallas.FrmVisImags$Hilosv.run(FrmVisImags.java:282)
```

The code for the threads is:

```
public FrmVisualizaImags() {
    initComponents(); 
    bandera = false; 
    // setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
    HilosProc hilosprc = new HilosProc(); 
    hilosprc.start(); 
    Hilosv hlv = new Hilosv(); 
    hlv.start(); 
}
```

Comment: The code for the threads is:   public FrmVisImags() {
        initComponents();
        bandera = false;
//        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        HilosProc hilosprc = new HilosProc();
        hilosprc.start();
        Hilosv hlv = new Hilosv();
        hlv.start();
    }

Comment: Have you tried `Tesseract1` class?